# How can I extract the maximum value from a Histogram?

Tags: graphics

In Mathematica 8.04 I've created a histogram of returns on a stock using:

```
returns = FinancialData["SP500", "Return", {Date[] - {5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, Date[]}, "Value"];
μ = Mean[returns];
h = Histogram[returns, 300, "PDF"];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

where "returns" is a list of the daily returns, and I want 300 bins in the probability density method. Next, I would like to draw a line that represents the mean of the returns so I use:

```
meanLine = Graphics[{Thick, Darker[Green], Line[{{μ, 0}, {μ, maxFreq + 2}}]}];
```

The problem is that I need to calculate the highest y-value for the line, which should be equal to the count of the data points in the bin with the most points (I've called this `maxFreq` above). I am currently setting this value manually because I don't know how to extract it from the histogram (h). Note that the x-coordinate of this line (`μ`) is simply the mean of the returns.

I've tried looking at `FullForm[h]` to see if I could figure out how to extract the data. Buried within that output is the following:

```
List[List[Rectangle[List[-0.0015, 0.], List[-0.001, 54.0111]
```

which shows that I want to set maxFreq = 54.0111. So, I suppose that I want to use the `Max` function, but I don't know how to access the heights of each bin. I think that I need to use some variation of the `Part` function, but I can't figure out how. Any clues would be appreciated.

Here is the code that will generate what I'm looking for, but maxFreq is manually entered:

```
returns = FinancialData["SP500", "Return", {Date[] - {5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, Date[]}, "Value"];
μ = Mean[returns];
h = Histogram[returns, 300, "PDF"];
maxFreq = 54;
meanLine = Graphics[{Thick, Darker[Green],Line[{{μ, 0}, {μ, maxFreq + 2}}]}];
Show[h, meanLine]
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As mentioned by others, use `HistogramList`.  You can even use the resulting information to generate the plot without recomputing the information:

```
{bins, heights} = HistogramList[returns, 300, "PDF"];
maxFreq = Max[heights];
Histogram[returns, {bins}, heights &, 
 Epilog -> {{Thick, Darker[Green], 
    Line[{{μ, 0}, {μ, maxFreq + 2}}]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: (Note, I kept the `+2` on the height of the line.)

Comment: Isn't `Histogram` supposed to return 300 bins with this  command? `HistogramList[returns, 300, "PDF"][[2]] // Length` says it's 413. Any idea?

Comment: It's a fuzzy 300, so that the boundaries are on "nice" numbers.  `{"Raw", 300}` will use 300, but then the boundaries won't be at nice values.  (Maybe that's not an issue with 300 bins, though.)

Comment: That's totally undocumented. Doc page says "n:  use n bins".

Comment: I am 1000% aware of that.

Comment: OK, question then is: Why isn't it documented?

Comment: @Brett and Sjoerd and Andy, thank you. I completely forgot about HistogramList. I ran into that one a few days ago, but there are so many functions. I'll accept Brett's answer, but vote up the others as well. All great answers.

Comment: @BrettChampion: as Sjoerd pointed out, I also encountered that behavior: "n" has a "jumpy" behavior. E.g., increasing it slightly (20 -> 25) might have no effect, but then (->26) you suddenly get a much finer histogram. I would consider this a bug (as in "not working as documented", and apparently not as in "not working as intended")

Answer (score 8):

If you have version 8 you could use `HistogramList`. It returns a list of bins and a list of heights for those bins.

```
HistogramList[returns, 300, "PDF"][[2]] // Max // N

(* ===> 54.01111994 *)
```

For those with versions <8: you could use the third argument of `Histogram` to make a kind of poor-man's `HistogramList`:

```
Reap[Histogram[returns, 300, (Sow[{#1, #2}]; #2) &];]
```

returns a list of bins and *counts*. In this case, you don't use counts but want probability density (PDF), so you have to calculate that from the bin size and the counts.

Comment: Oh that internet delay!

Comment: @AndyRoss Ha, beat you by a minute  ;-)

Comment: Probably the time incurred by using Part instead of the 2nd argument to Ordering :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `HistogramList` to generate the bins and their heights corresponding to a histogram and then use `Sort[hts][[-1]]` to obtain your result.

```
With[{res = N@HistogramList[returns, 300, "PDF"][[2]]}, Sort[res][[-1]]]

Out[104]= 54.0111
```

Comment: What do you have against `Max`?

Comment: Nothing in particular :)  It began with my wishing for the R function WhichIsMax which gives the index of the maximum value.  I had originally written the code in that way and then posted before fully simplifying it.

Comment: @AndyRoss There's `Ordering` for that (WhichIsMax I mean). `Ordering[{2, 4, 1, 7, 3}, -1]` ==> `{4}`

Comment: Exactly.  The original code snippet had Ordering[res][[-1]]. This should teach me to avoid working with R and Mathematica at the same time while posting!

Comment: No, don't use Part there. Use Ordering's second argument; it's much faster. It prevents Ordering from performing an unnecessary full sort.

Answer (score 2):

You could just fish the data from the histogram itself :

```
maxFreq=Max[Flatten[h[[1, 2, 2, 2]]][[All, 2, 2]]]
```

Comment: There is at least some danger in doing this however since the internal structure of the object may change between versions.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was trying to get at, but it looks like HistogramList will be a lot easier and I'll remember what it means in a few months.